# Validating date in Unix

Tags: date, unix

I have a scenario as below:

I will be getting two dates viz. start_dt and end_dt in yyyyMMdd format as arguments to my Unix Script.

I have to loop through each of the dates starting from start_dt till end_dt incrementing by a day each time.

The script I have written is as below:

```
start_date=$1
end_date=$2

#verify dates
if ! date -d "$start_date" 2>&1 > /dev/null ; 
then echo "start date is invalid" ; exit 1
fi

if ! date -d "$end_date" 2>&1 > /dev/null ; 
then echo "end date is invalid" ; exit 1
fi

#set current and end date
curr_dt=$(date -d "$start_date")
end_dt=$(date -d "$end_date +1 hours")

#loop over all dates
while [ "$end_dt" != "$curr_dt" ] 
do
   echo $curr_dt        

         # increment the date
   curr_dt=$(date -d "$curr_dt +1 hours")
done
```

However, I am getting below error when I am running with input arguments as 20140128 and 20140130:

```
date: invalid date `20140130 +1 hours'
Tue Jan 28 00:00:00 EST 2014

date: invalid date `Tue Jan 28 00:00:00 EST 2014 +1 hours'
```

Comment: It is working fine to me on `date (GNU coreutils) 8.20`

Comment: If you want to work a day at a time, why do you add `+1 hours` instead of `+ 1 days`?

Comment: The date parser in coreutils is designed to try to make sense of whatever a human types at it, and is therefore far too DWIMmy to be reliable for this kind of task. Unfortunately, nothing better is conveniently accessible from shell -- I strongly recommend you consider rewriting the entire program in Perl or Python, both of which have excellent date-handling libraries, and which are also just plain better programming languages all-round.

Comment: @Vicky: Date arithmetic with `date (GNU coreutils) 6.9` produces error messages like you're seeing, however it works if the input date is provided in "RFC 2822" format (eg `Mon, 07 Aug 2006 12:34:56 -0600`). Thankfully, the `-R` switch of the same binary generates this output.